# Effect of grind size on LDL cholesterol levels in French press coffee

Tags: health, french-press

Keeping all other factors (e.g. water temperature, extraction time) the same, does grind size affect the [LDL cholesterol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-density_lipoprotein) levels in French press coffee? If so, how are the two related?

Comment: Could you please take a look at these two: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/413/does-caffeine-raise-cholesterol-good-or-bad and https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2422/are-there-health-risks-to-eating-coffee/3564#3564 ?

Comment: @MTSan I'm familiar with those, but neither touch on the role of grind size given a French press (or other non-paper non-pressure brew method). I think it's conceivable grind size may impact the amount of oil (thus LDL) in the final product, but I'm looking for studies testing that hypothesis.

Comment: Increasing extraction may increase LDL level if coffee does not immediately emit all its cholesterol in the beginning of extraction. Then, finer grind means more cholesterol. However, I'm unaware of the extraction dynamics of the cholesterol of coffee.

Comment: Not really much to study there. The finer the grind, the higher the extraction, the more oils are present in the unfiltered coffee. Thus higher impact on LDL cholesterol levels. I doubt it has a huge impact, but logic dictates that it has at least some marginal effect.

Comment: There was apparently a study that done on the effects of grind size on lipid extraction. I can tell you the results without having read the paper (can't access it), but if you want to buy it here is the link: https://www.tib.eu/de/suchen/id/BLCP%3ACN081430365/Lipids-in-Coffee-Brews-Impact-of-Grind-Size-Water/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does caffeine raise cholesterol (good or bad)?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/413/does-caffeine-raise-cholesterol-good-or-bad)

Comment: @technical_difficulty no, this question is about cholesterol levels being affected by grind size in a metal filtered brew (like French press). That question is about possible health effects of caffeine.